# onBeforeUnload/unload

Tags: javascript, jquery

In Javascript, I keep seeing posts about how one should not try to use onBeforeUnload or unload() in jQuery, citing security issues.  Could someone explain in greater detail what these issues are?

On that note, I have also found that neither of these work in any browser I've tried.  Even something simple like this:

```
$(window).unload(function(){
alert('hello');
});
```

Is this intentional, or no?

Comment: Where do you keep seeing these posts?

Comment: Nevermind.  I just saw that Chrome blocks alerts in unload.

Answer (score 1):

You might have mixed it up with the issues concerning usability??

I use it as native js

```
window.onunload = function(e) {
   return 'Dialog text here.';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You con't use an Alert inside your function for simple raison that onunload is a pop-up so the display your text (HELLO) just but it in the return or try this:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event) {
                    event.returnValue = 'hello';
            });
```